# How to send and use data in ejs or jade with node js server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am sending localstorage data from ajax to node js server with ajax, so that to use that data to decorate html page with ejs or jade. I tried to send my data to ejs or jade by rendering it after getting with app.post. It compiles, but I can not find movies variable in ejs file.

```
app.post('/notes' , function (req , res) {
   var name = req.body;
   res.render('/bucket',{movies:name});
});
```

In client side I wrote like this, it can not find movies variable here:

```
function postData() {
        var clicked;
        if (localStorage.getItem("liked") === null)
            clicked = [];
        else
            clicked = localStorage.getItem("liked");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/notes',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : clicked,
            success: function (msg) {

            }
        });
    }
postData();
alert ("<%=movies%>");
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting `alert("<%=movies%>");` after `postData();` - try putting `alert(msg.movies);` in the success handler that is now empty and which is the only place (in your example) where you can use the AJAX response.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use that data in ejs files. In detail, I want to get a huge array with data and post it on page with ejs loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your `bucket.jade` template, try including the below lines after your `postData()` function.

```
  script.
    alert("#{movies}")
```

I tried a example here, and it worked perfectly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: is there a way to do it with ejs? As I think, if it works then